# refresh a page on button click - jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have a very small jquery app with one button and a jquery function. here is the ode:

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function swapcookie() {
        $.cookie('IsMobile', 'False', { expires: 3000, path: '/' });

    }


</script>
```

HTML

```
<a class="force-desktop" href="" data-role="button" onclick="swapcookie();">Force desktop</a>
```

My goal is to change the value of the cookie (which works fine), and then reload the page. But strangely when I click the button, nothing happens. Also I tried putting current url in href="" but that didn't work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function swapcookie() {
        $.cookie('IsMobile', 'False', { expires: 3000, path: '/' });
        location.reload(); //Reload the current page.
    }
</script>
```

Comment: this works. Any ideas why empty href="" wouldn't work? It works on normal page but jquery mobile.

Comment: The href attribute wan't designed to be empty, so it's behavior may vary depending on browser implementations. I recommend you not putting the href attribute or one of those example : <a href="#" ...>... or <a href="#" ...> or <a href="EnableJavascript.html" ...>